# .NET Core 3.1 System.IO.Port - System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required. (Parameter 'count')

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 Web API but it happens also on a simple plain console app. And I begin investigating but unfortunate I don't know why or what could be the reason for `CheckReadWriteArguments` count be a non-negative number.

I've checked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialPort.cs) and also [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialStream.cs).

Any help or guidance appreciated.

Why I'm using .NET Core and not python? Because trying to have a web application on rasbperry pi that will send and read commands via Serial Communication to an arduino device. And because I like .NET Core more

Exception below:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative
> number required. (Parameter 'count')    at
> System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.CheckReadWriteArguments(Byte[] array,
> Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] array, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32
> count, Int32 timeout)    at
> System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.InternalRead(Char[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count, Int32 timeout, Boolean countMultiByteCharsAsOne)    at
> System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> count)    at ConsoleApp9.Program.Read() in
> C:\Users\Mircea\source\repos\ConsoleApp9\Program.cs:line 51    at
> ConsoleApp9.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\Mircea\source\repos\ConsoleApp9\Program.cs:line 32 Aborted

Source code for console app.

```
class Program
{
    static SerialPort _serialPort;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        // Set the read/write timeouts
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 1500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 1500;

        _serialPort.Open();

        _serialPort.DataReceived += _serialPort_DataReceived;

        while (true)
        {
            Read();
        }

        _serialPort.Close();

        Task.Delay(50000).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.EventType);
        Console.WriteLine(sender.ToString());
    }

    public static void Read()
    {
        try
        {
            char[] asd = new char[255];
            int message = _serialPort.Read(asd,1,30);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.WriteLine(asd.ToString());
        }
        catch (TimeoutException) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For whoever has issues on netCore be careful that `_serialPort.Read`   or `_serialPort.ReadLine()`  will wait for a message to come from the device (in my case Arduino).

Also on the write part. try to use write(byte[]) and not via String, because it inserts different characters

Example ->

```
var stringMessage = "Message"
 var sendMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringMessage);
            _serialPort.Write(sendMessage, 0, sendMessage.Length);
```